# Excel sum values if column is within <90 days

Tags: excel

I have an excel table with quantities of produce sold on various dates. I would like to sum the values of the quantities in the dates columns only if the produce was sold within the last `90` days.

I have tried multiple formulas including:

```
=SUMIFS(C2:F2, C$1:F$1, ">"&TODAY()-90)
```

and

```
=SUMIFS(C2:F2, $C$1:$F$1, ">="&TODAY()-90, $C$1:$F$1, "<="&TODAY())
```

All the formulas I have tried are either summing all columns regardless of their date. Or, they are returning 0. What am I missing?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are true date value then below formula should work-

```
=SUMIFS(C2:F2,$C$1:$F$1,">="&TODAY()-90)
```

And if they are string then could try-

```
=SUMPRODUCT((--($C$1:$F$1)>=TODAY()-90)*(C2:F2))
```

[image]

Comment: The second formula seems to work. Thanks!